# Extend Filter functionality to use only if variable have value

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I am using the django framework for make an blog app.
my django version is `Django version 4.0.4`

i am supposed to do filter the data as per Title And category that  blog does have
my code is as follow

```
searchTitle = request.GET.get('searchTitle')
searchCat = request.GET.get('searchCat', '')

if searchTitle or searchCat:
    blogs = Blog.objects.filter(blog_title__icontains=searchTitle).order_by('-blog_id')
    if searchCat:
        blogs = Blog.objects.filter(blog_title__icontains=searchTitle,blog_category=searchCat).order_by('-blog_id')
else:
    blogs = Blog.objects.all().order_by('-blog_id')
```

This is working perfect but this doesn't make sense since it does not follow `DRY principle`

Here i've written `Blog.object.filter` code twice for search. so i want to minimize that and that problem in one line if possible.
so could you guys guide over me

Comment: Maybe [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/) is what you are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce this using dictionary

```
searchTitle = request.GET.get('searchTitle')
searchCat = request.GET.get('searchCat', '')

d = {}

if searchTitle or searchCat:
    d.update({"blog_title__icontains": searchTitle})
    if searchCat:
        d.update({"blog_category": searchCat})
if d:
    Blog.objects.filter(**d).order_by("-blog_id")
else:
    blogs = Blog.objects.all().order_by('-blog_id')
```

Comment: answer seems meaningful to me.

Comment: Thanks its correct answer but dont you think still code length is high and we can short that.
Do we have another solution or we've to continue with this ?

Comment: I can short this code but it depends what you are using and creating if you are using ModelViewSets then you can use django-filters and just mention the fields to be filtered it will automatically does all this stuff

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple, but a single line would not be readable. `.filter` doesn't send a query, so the operations can be added one by one. Simple ifs and a few lines make it the most readable form you can achieve here:

```
search_title = request.GET.get('searchTitle')
search_cat = request.GET.get('searchCat', '')

blogs = Blog.objects.all().order_by('-blog_id')  # no query sent to db

if search_title:
    blogs = blogs.filter(blog_title__icontains=search_title)  # no query sent

if search_cat:
    blogs = blogs.filter(blog_category=search_cat)  # no query sent

blog_ids = [blog.id for blog in blog]  # single query sent here
```

The oneliner, would be this (since empty string `""` parameter in `icontains` returns all objects):

```
search_title = request.GET.get('searchTitle', '')
search_cat = request.GET.get('searchCat', '')

blogs = Blog.objects.filter(
    blog_title__icontains=search_title,
    blog_category=search_cat,
).order_by('-blog_id')
```

Note: I have changed the names, because *camelCase* in Python is reserved for class names, variables should use *snake_case*. That's the convention anyway.